# I am getting an error when sending hidden value data as array on server side

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

I am using Handlebars as my templating engine and am new to handlebars. I passed over data from an API(edamam recipe search api). When trying to send back the array of ingredients attached to each recipe card using a hidden value in the form I get an error on the server side. Console shows

> [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object] [object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object]

when trying to log it out on server side. Not sure what is going on. Code Below:

```
<div class="container">
  <header class="jumbotron">
    <div class=container></div>
    <h1>{{currentUser.username}}</h1>
    <h1>Press save to add the recipes to your dashboard</h1>
    <p>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="/{{currentUser.username}}/recipes/dashboard">Go To Your Dashboard</a>
    </p>
  </header>

  <div class="row text-center" style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap">
    {{#each data}}
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="{{recipe.image}}" alt="Recipe Pic">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>
            {{recipe.label}}
          </h4>
          <h5>
            Ingredients
          </h5>

{{!-- recipe.ingredients is an array of ingredient objects with text as a key --}}

          {{#each recipe.ingredients}} 
          <p>{{text}}</p>
          {{/each}}
        </div>
        <p>
         <form id="buttonDesign" action="/recipes/dashboard" method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" name="recName" value="{{this.recipe.label}}"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="recImage" value="{{this.recipe.image}}"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="recUrl" value="{{this.recipe.url}}"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="recIngredients" value "{{this.recipe.ingredients}}"/>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
          </form>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
   {{/each}}
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

As mentioned above When I log out req.body.recIngredients on server side I get `[object, Object]` error.

Comment: missing `=` on last hidden field ?

Comment: missing = on recIngredients field
-->AND--> button type is required to form submit --->
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>

Answer (score 1):

The data you are passing using your templating engine is the direct objects e.g. {{this.recipe.ingredients}} so when this object "this.recipe.ingredients" gets converted to string this converts to "[[Object object]]" which is the default string response provided by the Object#toString() method. What you need to do is first convert your objects to string and then assign that to html element's attribute values. 
For conversion you can use "JSON.stringify(this.recipe.ingredients)" which will convert your entire object into a JSON formatted string.
I don't know about "Handlebars templating engine" but this should work : 
{{JSON.stringify(this.recipe.ingredients)}}.
And yes you forgot to put "=" `<input type="hidden" name="recIngredients" value "{{this.recipe.ingredients}}"/>` to relate value attribute with its real value which is "{{this.recipe.ingredients}}".

Answer (score 0):

Actually saying you code works as expected. As we're placing a JAVASCRIPT object ( this.recipe.ingredients ) in the hidden field, we need to convert that JAVASCRIPT object into a string value, in order to submit it as FORM data.

To make the conversion, you need to create & register handlebars helper like below

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('json', function(context) {
    return JSON.stringify(context);
});
```

Also you need to use that helper in appropriate place like below.

```
<input type="hidden" name="recIngredients" value="{{json this.recipe.ingredients}}"/>
```

BTW, if you make the hidden field as text field, you could find the problems easily ( I hope ).

Please confirm that, this is working or not for you :)